# Deserialize XML to object array with different name to XML element

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, deserialization

I have an XML structure like this:

```
<QueryResult>
    <Submission>
        <Sections>
            <Section>
                <!--Section Data-->
            </Section>
        </Sections>
    </Submission>
</QueryResult>
```

I am trying to deserialize - I never have to serialize - this to a `Submission` object, e.g:

```
public partial class Submission : CanvasModel
{
    private DateTime _date;
    private DateTime _deviceDate;
    private List<Section> _sections = new List<Section>();

    [XmlIgnore]
    public ICollection<Section> Sections
    {
        get
        {
            return _sections;
        }
        set
        {
            _sections = value.ToList();
        }
    }

    //[XmlArrayItem("Section", IsNullable = false)]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(Section), ElementName = "Sections", IsNullable = false)]
    public Section[] SectionsArray
    {
        get
        {
            return _sections.ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            _sections = new List<Section>(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Yet the XML element `Sections` is not deserializing. It only works when the `Section[]` property has the same name as the XML element, `Sections`. I am wrestling with the `XmlArrayItem` attribute and am losing. Elsewhere when the names differ, I use the `XmlElement` attribute to specify the element name, and everything works fine. However, I am not allowed to use `XmlElement` and `XmlArrayItem` on the same property.

What is the correct way for me to use the `XmlArrayItem` attribute to deserialize the `Sections` XML element to the `SectionsArray` property?

BTW, I want the widely used property, `public ICollection<Section> Sections`, that I need for my EF data model, to have the document name, `Sections`, for several reasons, so just swapping the two names is really my last resort. I want to keep the current `SectionsArray` property purely for deserialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There would be *two* ways to get around this by using xml serialization attributes.

First is [AncientSyntax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3760643/ancientsyntax)'s answer which I agree with, with the sole amendment that you have to specify node name explicitly for the array.

```
    [XmlRootAttribute( "Submission", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public class Submission : CanvasModel { 
        private List<Section> _sections = new List<Section>();

    [XmlIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Section> Sections
    {
        get { return _sections; }
        set { _sections = value.ToList(); }
    }

    [XmlArray(ElementName="Sections")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Section", IsNullable = false)]
    public Section[] SectionsArray
    {
        get { return _sections.ToArray(); }
        set { _sections = value.ToList(); }
    }
    }
```

The less straightforward way is to wrap your array into an intermediate type 
like:

```
[SerializableAttribute()]
[XmlRootAttribute("Sections", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Sections {
    private Section[] sectionField;
    [XmlElementAttribute("Section")]
    public Section[] Section
    {
      get { return this.sectionField; }
      set { this.sectionField = value; }
    }
  }
```

and use it instead of the sections array:

```
private Sections _sectionsArrayWrapper;
[XmlElement(typeof(Sections), ElementName = "Sections", IsNullable = false)]    
public Sections SectionsArrayWrapper
{
      // your job to go from array wrapper to collection
}
```

Both definitions work with:

```
[SerializableAttribute()]
[XmlRootAttribute("Section", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class Section { }
```

and `public class CanvasModel { }`

This was tested with the xml you provided.

Comment: And we have a winner! Adding the array element name did it.

Answer (score 3):

The ElementName should be the name of the contained xml element, in this case Section.

In addition it looks like you should be using XmlArrayAttribute as well as an XmlArrayItemAttribute.

```
[XmlArray]
[XmlArrayItem(typeof(Section), ElementName = "Section", IsNullable = false)]
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for an example.

Comment: Adding `XmlArrayAttribute` seems to make no difference. If the class name differs from the element name, I still get zero Sections in all cases.